# How can i use templete model as javascript object

Tags: adonis.js, edge.js

I need to use edge.js template model object as javascript object.

In edge.js template engine i can do like this:

```
<h1>{{ model.name }}</h1>
```

but how can i use model like js object like this:

```
<script>
  console.log({{model}})
</script>
```